# .class element, why this doesn't do anything?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn [css](/questions/tagged/css) and I came by something I don't understand.

So I have this line of code in html:

```
<ul class="weblist">
    <li>Coffee Brur</li>
    <li>Taco Finder</li>
    <li>CSS Selector Finder</li>
    <li>HTML Formatter</li>
</ul>
```

And this line in [css](/questions/tagged/css) file:

```
.weblist ul {
  color: red;
}
```

And I wonder why it doesn't do anything. From what I get, it should take all the descendants of the `unordered` list with the `weblist` class, and apply them the red color, but it does nothing. I would like it to make all the list elements of this particular `unordered` list to appear red.

Comment: should just be ul.weblist{color: red}

Comment: `.weblist ul` means *a `ul` nested inside an element with class `weblist`*…

Comment: What ConsoleLog is suggesting is a selector that selects all `ul` elements *with* the class `weblist`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following css

```
ul.weblist{
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply it on the list item if you want to change the color of the text.

```
.weblist li {
color: red;
}
```

Edit: In this case it works, but the other solution to wrap another div around your list is maybe a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

`.weblist ul` means means that your `ul` is nested in an element that have `weblist` class.
So to make your css work you need to write following HTML

your css:

```
.weblist ul {
      color: red;
    }
```

and HTML

```
<div class="weblist">
     <ul>
        <li>Coffee Brur</li>
        <li>Taco Finder</li>
        <li>CSS Selector Finder</li>
        <li>HTML Formatter</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.weblist ul` means to be apply to an `ul` element INSIDE a `.weblist` class element (here in my example, it's `test`)

```css
.weblist ul {
  color: red;
}

ul.weblist { /* <- This is what you want */
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="weblist">
    <li>Coffee Brur</li>
    <li>Taco Finder</li>
    <li>CSS Selector Finder</li>
    <li>HTML Formatter</li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <!-- here you have a <ul> inside weblist class element -->
        test
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
And this line in css file:
```

Comment: ul is not valid child of ul ... ul can only have li as child